# wordpress ajax фильтр для кастомных типов записей

Tags: wordpress, ajax

Вопрос по кастомным типам и ajax фильтре. Я наворотил такой огород который работает но мне не нравится реализация, хочется разделить фильтр и вывод результата,
сделать вывод в шаблоне не пойму как это реализовать?
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

**код из function.php**

```
function true_filter_function(){
   global $post;
                                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                                $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'kursy',
                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'posts_per_page' => 15,
                                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                                'paged' => $paged,
                                'meta_query' => array(
                                array('key' => 'datestart'),
                                ),
                                );

                                if( isset( $_GET['dateStart'] ) && $_GET['dateStart'] || isset( $_GET['dateEnd'] ) && $_GET['dateEnd'] || isset( $_GET['stype'] ) && $_GET['stype'] || isset( $_GET['city'] ) &&  $_GET['city']  )
                                $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' );

                                if( isset( $_GET['dateStart'] ) && $_GET['dateStart'] && isset( $_GET['dateEnd'] ) && $_GET['dateEnd']){
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'datestart',
                                    'value' => array($_GET['dateStart'],$_GET['dateEnd']),
                                    'compare' => 'between',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                );
                            }else{
                                if( isset( $_GET['dateStart'] ) && $_GET['dateStart'])
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'datestart',
                                    'value' => $_GET['dateStart'],
                                    'compare' => '>',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                );
                                if( isset( $_GET['dateEnd'] ) && $_GET['dateEnd'])
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'datestart',
                                    'value' => $_GET['dateEnd'],
                                    'compare' => '<',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                );

                            }
                                if( isset( $_GET['stype'] ) && $_GET['stype'] )
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'stype',
                                    'value' => $_GET['stype'],
                                    'type' => 'CHAR',
                                    'compare' => '='
                                );
                                if( isset( $_GET['city'] ) && $_GET['city'] )
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'city',
                                    'value' => $_GET['city'],
                                    'type' => 'CHAR',
                                    'compare' => '='
                                );
                           $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                            if( $query->have_posts() ) :
                                 while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                                echo '<tr>';
                                 echo  '<td>'. date("d.m.Y", strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'datestart', true))).'</td>';
                                 echo   '<td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title(). '</a></td>';
                                 echo    '<td>'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'city', true).'</td>';
                                 echo    '<td>'; 
                                 $seminarType = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stype', true);
                                if ($seminarType == 'seminar') {
                                echo  "Семинар";
                                } elseif ($seminarType == 'webinar') {
                                echo "Вебинар";
                                } else {
                                 echo  "Семинар";
                                }
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'doc', true).'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            endwhile;
                            else:
                            wp_reset_query();
                            endif;
                       die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
```

**код из js файла**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Обработка...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data){
                filter.find('button').text('Применить'); // changing the button label back
                $('#response').html(data); // insert data
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: а как это вообще в теме используется?  есть какая-то функция без привязки к хуку, есть какой-то ajax вызов. можете показать как это связано?

Comment: В шаблоне форма с фильтрами с айдишником #filter и вывод идет в таблицу

Comment: а вывод при первом вызове шаблоне как идет всех курсов?

Comment: Да при загрузке страницы выполняется ajax запрос пустой формы

Comment: Мне не нравится то что надо выводить это с помощью echo из function.php файла, может можно как-то передать отфильтрованный массив в шаблон в таблицу?

Comment: не понятно значение - global $post;. а потом в цикле get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stype', true); как вообще $post связан с результатом постов  WP_Query

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev $query->the_post() устанавливает значения глобальной переменной $post

Comment: В каком шаблоне? Нормальный у вас код, более или менее, не заморачивайтесь.

Comment: По безопасности нехорошо, нет nonce

Comment: Это нормально такой огород в function.php ? Так как выводится  по 15 записей на странице то у меня тогда слетает пагинация, все равно какая-то байда получается.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так

При инициализации post_type указал атрибут 'has_archive' => true,

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'kursy',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Курсы' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Курсы' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

Тогда Ваш тип записи был бы доступен по адресу http://yoursite.com/kursy/

Чтоб создать персональный шаблон для архива нужно создать шаблона archive-kursy.php (archive-{posttype}.php file)

Пример шаблона archive-kursy.php

```
<?php
get_header();

?>

<!--- фильтры -->

<?php

global $query_string;

parse_str($query_string, $args);

if( isset( $_GET['dateStart'] ) && $_GET['dateStart'] || isset( $_GET['dateEnd'] ) && $_GET['dateEnd'] || isset( $_GET['stype'] ) && $_GET['stype'] || isset( $_GET['city'] ) &&  $_GET['city']  )
                                $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' );

                                if( isset( $_GET['dateStart'] ) && $_GET['dateStart'] && isset( $_GET['dateEnd'] ) && $_GET['dateEnd']){
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'datestart',
                                    'value' => array($_GET['dateStart'],$_GET['dateEnd']),
                                    'compare' => 'between',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                );
                            }else{
                                if( isset( $_GET['dateStart'] ) && $_GET['dateStart'])
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'datestart',
                                    'value' => $_GET['dateStart'],
                                    'compare' => '>',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                );
                                if( isset( $_GET['dateEnd'] ) && $_GET['dateEnd'])
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'datestart',
                                    'value' => $_GET['dateEnd'],
                                    'compare' => '<',
                                    'type' => 'DATE'
                                );

                            }
                                if( isset( $_GET['stype'] ) && $_GET['stype'] )
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'stype',
                                    'value' => $_GET['stype'],
                                    'type' => 'CHAR',
                                    'compare' => '='
                                );
                                if( isset( $_GET['city'] ) && $_GET['city'] )
                                $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                                    'key' => 'city',
                                    'value' => $_GET['city'],
                                    'type' => 'CHAR',
                                    'compare' => '='
                                );

query_posts( $args );

if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();

                            $post_id = get_the_ID();  
    
                            echo '<tr>';
                                 echo  '<td>'. date("d.m.Y", strtotime(get_post_meta($post_id, 'datestart', true))).'</td>';
                                 echo   '<td><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' . get_the_title(). '</a></td>';
                                 echo    '<td>'. get_post_meta($post_id, 'city', true).'</td>';
                                 echo    '<td>'; 
                                 $seminarType = get_post_meta($post_id, 'stype', true);
                                if ($seminarType == 'seminar') {
                                echo  "Семинар";
                                } elseif ($seminarType == 'webinar') {
                                echo "Вебинар";
                                } else {
                                 echo  "Семинар";
                                }
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. get_post_meta($post_id, 'doc', true).'</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';

endwhile; endif;
get_footer();
```

По запросу с фильтрами отправлял аяксом запрос на http://yoursite.com/kursy/?city=&stype=...

Но в возвращаемом результате отсекал вывод верхушки и фильтров. Заменял бы результирующую таблицу курсов новым результатом. Так Вам не нужно использовать дополнительных функций в functions.php и Вы работаете в рамках шаблона архива